# Race condition with nonblocking assignment in UVM driver

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to execute for a synchronous driver, I aligned the driven signals to the clock edge as the below. I used nonblocking assignment to avoid race conditions in the UVM driver.

When I ran the driver, I got this printed out:

```
myCmd.start: 1
myCmd.start: 0
```

but, I expected as the below:

```
myCmd.start: 0
myCmd.start: 1
```

In the waveform viewer, I have checked the signal is correctly working.
Only `uvm_info()` is not working correctly. If I add `#1`

`#1; uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("myCmd.start:%h", my_master_vif.dut_command), UVM_LOW)`

then I can print the correct value.

Is this not enough to handle the race condition for `uvm_info()` in the driver? How can I avoid this problem?

```
class my_master_driver_c extends uvm_driver#(my_frame_c);

  virtual my_if my_master_vif;
   //...
  task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);

    while (1) begin
      begin

        forever begin
          @(posedge my_master_vif.dut_clock_i iff (my_master_vif.reset))
          seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
          drive_transfer(req);
          #10;
          seq_item_port.item_done(req);
        end
      end
    end
  endtask
  //...
  
  task drive_transfer (input my_frame_c trans);    
    
    @(posedge my_master_vif.dut_clock_i iff (my_master_vif.reset));
    my_master_vif.dut_command <= 0;
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("myCmd.start:%h", my_master_vif.dut_command), UVM_LOW)
    
    @(posedge my_master_vif.dut_clock_i iff (my_master_vif.reset));
    my_master_vif.dut_command <= 1;
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("myCmd.start:%h", my_master_vif.dut_command), UVM_LOW)
    //...

  endtask : drive_transfer

  //...

endclass
```

This is my interface:

```
interface my_if 
   (
    input clock_my, 
          reset,
    inout wire w_dut_command,
    output reg dut_clock_i,
    //...

    );

  timeunit 1ps;
  timeprecision 1ps;    

  assign dut_clock_i   = clock_my;

  logic dut_command = 'bz;
        assign w_dut_command  = dut_command;    

  clocking driver_cb @(posedge clock_my);
    default input #1 output #1;

    inout dut_command;

  endclocking    

endinterface : my_if
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point out an important problem, you are not doing synchronous driving, but just doing non-blocking assignment. **Although synchronous drives use the same operator syntax as nonblocking variable assignments, they are not the same.** Actually, you are not using your clocking block in your current code. To be precise, you just drive the interface signal asynchronously, but use clocking events for synchronization. Conceptually speaking, *Synchronous drive* only occurs at the output of the clocking block, In other words, you need to access the domain of the clocking block by `my_master_vif.driver_cb.dut_command` instead of `my_master_vif.dut_command`. The results of driving these two signals are different, you can try to drive them separately, and then view the waveforms of these two signals simultaneously in the simulation tool to compare. **Ref** *SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017* ***14.16*** *Synchronous drives*.

In addition, as in the following structure, according to timing control, the execution of statement A and statement B will not theoretically occur at the same time, and there will be at least one clock cycle difference between them. There is no time information in the output of your question description.

```
@(posedge clk);
// ... ...
// A statement
// ... ...
@(posedge clk);
// ... ...
// B statement
// ... ...
```

In your case, you can equate `uvm_info` to `$display` task. So actually your question becomes a question of who executes first between non-blocking assignment and `$display` task.

```
dut_command <= 1;
@(posedge clk);
dut_command <= 0;                                      // ?
$display("@%0t, dut_command: %h", $time, dut_command); // ?
```

According to SystemVerilog's simulation scheduling semantics, this is unambiguous and there is no race. The `$display` is executed in the active region, and the update of the non-blocking assignment occurs in the NBA region. So the result will output `dut_command: 1`, refer to the picture below. If you want to print `dut_command: 0`, you can add `#1` or replace `$display` with `$strobe`.

```
dut_command <= 1;
@(posedge clk);
dut_command <= 0;
$display("@%0t, dut_command: %h", $time, dut_command);       // 1
// #1 $display("@%0t, dut_command: %h", $time, dut_command); // 0
// $strobe("@%0t, dut_command: %h", $time, dut_command);     // 0
```

[image: Event scheduling regions]

For details to see *SystemVerilog IEEE Std 1800-2017* **chapter 4** Scheduling semantics and this paper: [SystemVerilog Event Regions, Race Avoidance & Guidelines](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events.pdf). In addition, race condition generally refers to situations that occur in the same event region and result in uncertain results. If you want to find a real case about race condition, you can also search related questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), I have also answered a related [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75647262/14395049), you can refer to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75650874/14395049).

Finally, back to your question again, if the understanding is correct, your first transaction driver will output:

```
myCmd.start: z
myCmd.start: 0
```

because your `dut_command`  is initialized to `'bz`. And each subsequent transaction driver will output:

```
myCmd.start: 1
myCmd.start: 0
```

To avoid this problem, In addition to add `#1` or replace `uvm_info` with `$strobe`, you can also just change all the non-blocking assignment to the blocking assignment like `my_master_vif.dut_command = 1`, which may be better solution.

Even if you change to a synchronous drive `my_master_vif.driver_cb.dut_command <= 1`, the output will not change as you expected because the value of `driver_cb.dut_command` will change in the Re-NBA region by default. The read value of `driver_cb.dut_command` is still the last sampled value, and not the driven value just now, which is the feature of *Synchronous drives*. Therefore, if you drive the signal like this, you can refer to [toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic)'s suggestion:

> It is more common to print information only at the start (or end) of a transaction, using `req.print`, for example, which shows all the desired properties of the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

In normal operation, you should not use `uvm_info` to display information on every clock cycle *within* a transaction in your driver.  You'll end up with far too many messages in your log file, and there is no need for that fine-grained detail.  It is more common to print information only at the start (or end) of a transaction, using `req.print`, for example, which shows all the desired properties of the transaction.

On the other hand, if you are doing some **temporary** debugging of your driver code, you might be better off using `$strobe` instead of `uvm_info`.  I don't know how `uvm_info` is implemented in the class library, but you shouldn't rely on a specific implementation anyway.

Also, using `#1` is a good approach if you know that 1 is much shorter than the clock period.  Another approach is to use the opposite edge of the clock (`negedge` in your case).

Once you are done debugging, you should delete any display-type statements from your driver task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the task `uvm_wait_for_nba_region()`. This eliminates the time delay that `#1` or `negedge` would introduce and allows you to use `uvm_info`.

```
task drive_transfer (input my_frame_c trans);    
    
    @(posedge my_master_vif.dut_clock_i iff (my_master_vif.reset));
    my_master_vif.dut_command <= 0;
    uvm_wait_for_nba_region(); // <-------
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("myCmd.start:%h", my_master_vif.dut_command), UVM_LOW)
    
    @(posedge my_master_vif.dut_clock_i iff (my_master_vif.reset));
    my_master_vif.dut_command <= 1;
    uvm_wait_for_nba_region(); // <-------
    `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf("myCmd.start:%h", my_master_vif.dut_command), UVM_LOW)
    //...

  endtask : drive_transfer
```

Generally, if you are going to put print messages in your driver, you should use `UVM_HIGH` or `UVM_DEBUG`. Using `UVM_LOW` is very verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Using <= (Non blocking assignment) is causing your uvm_info statement not to see the update immediately. This goes to verilog basics on differences between <= and =.
But there are something that is not adding up, is you getting the output in swapped manner. Could you please paste the complete information with timing information, couple of statements before and after.